# Laravel eloquent query with nested whereDate

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have a table called `operators`
The columns are:

```
id, user_id, item_clicked, created_at, updated_at
```

I can confirm on one of these it has today's update_at
2019-08-05 showing as today.

This is a relational table.
operators belongs to users.

I'm attempting to get operators of users whereDate is today.
My code is:

```
  $ordersClicked = User::with('operators')
  ->whereDate('updated_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())
  ->get();
```

This returns an empty array.

Testing this works so I know the data I need is there.

```
  $ordersClicked = User::with('operators')
  ->get();

$operator = Operator::whereDate('updated_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->get();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ `Carbon::today()` returns `Y-m-d H:i:s`, if used like you are doing in a where clause and the database stores the value in `Y-m-d` format.

Why don't you try this:

```
$ordersClicked = User::with('operators')
  ->whereDate('updated_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'))
  ->get();
```

if that doesn't work; then it is possible the eloquent is applying the `where` clause on `updated_at` on the `User` table, instead of `Operator`. Did you mean to do something like this:

```
$ordersClicked = User::with(['operators' => function($query) {
    $query->where('updated_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'))
}])->get();
```

i.e. filter on the eager loaded collection? if this is what you intended, what will happen is it will return all users and only some operators that has the `updated_at` matching the criteria will have values, where others will be null.

Wouldn't it be better to reverse the query? i.e. make sure `Operator` has a `belongsTo` relationship on `User` model and query the data like this:

```
$operator = Operator::whereDate('updated_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())
    ->with('user')
    ->get();
```

Comment: The above two returned empty.  I thought about reversing the query but then I wrote some other code working around Users.  I could just fix rewrite that if there's no other options @Latheesan.

Comment: @FabricioG can you try `Querying Relationship Existence` i.e. using `whereHas` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence. Something like this: `$ordersClicked = User::with('operators')
  ->whereHas('operators', function($query) {
    $query->whereDate('updated_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())
  })
  ->get();`

Comment: It's strange the reverse Operator::with('user" also returns empty.  @Latheesan

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer based on the direction.  This actually worked reversing the with and whereDate:      $operator = Operator::whereDate('updated_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())
      ->with('user')->get();  @Latheesan please add it to the answer.